# Python Telegram Channel Reader

Tags: python, telethon

I've been scratching my head at this a while.  Trying to just do the simple act of creating a program that will automatically read in every new post from a Telegram channel into str or something that I can use to then create a bot. I've been looking for days and everything I've seen and tried doesn't seem to work for me.  Apologies cause I know this is probably stupid simple and there is an answer somewhere but the answer's I've seen just haven't worked or maybe I just don't get async at all.

```
import configparser
import json
import re
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id = 'xxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'


user_input_channel = 'https://t.me/Kucoin_news'
subjectFilter = ['']
levelFilter = ['']

client = TelegramClient(None, api_id, api_hash)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel)) 
async def newMessageListener(event):
    # Get message text 
    newMessage = event.message.message
    print(newMessage)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

```
/home/enigma/.config/spyder-py3/Bot.py:35: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
  client.start()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
/home/enigma/.config/spyder-py3/Bot.py:36: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UpdateMethods._run_until_disconnected' was never awaited
  client.run_until_disconnected()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Does async HAVE to be used with a telethon application like this? This will only be for reading one channels new posts, not several. By the time a new post comes out the Bot will easily have completed its task. I thought that since `client.start()` and `client.run_until_disconnected()` were outside of the async function they didn't need to be awaited?  Awaiting is just when you call a function inside of the async function correct?  I've tried to read on this subject but find the way they explain it confusing and long winded.

Comment: This code runs ok in my environment :|

Comment: hmm. That was something I was afraid of.  Thank you very much! This must be some issue that I have with my setup then.  thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

client.start() under `client = "ecc"`

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.